# JS convert PDF to base64 in local path

Tags: javascript, html

my project have this foldes:

```
 -html
    index.html   
   -css      
   -js
     my.js      
   -pdf
     test.pdf
```

I need to convert this "test.pdf" to base 64 and send by POST

I try use a function like this:

```
function getBase64() {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var file = new File("/pdf/test.pdf","r");

    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
       // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);

       reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
        return reader.result;
       };
       reader.onerror = function (error) {
         console.log('Error: ', error);
       };
    });
```

But I'm not the correct way to get past the folder path, or if I have to use another object and not File.

```
var file = new File("/pdf/test.pdf","r");
```

What's the best way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: this is on the server side? so you're using nodejs? - doesn't look like valid nodejs to me

Comment: not on server side. simple javascript.

Comment: exactly  simple javascript.